# shell programming in inventory book management

Tags: bash, shell

```
function add_new_book
{
  echo "1) add_new_book"

  echo -n "Title :"
    read title
  echo -n "Author :"
    read author
  echo -n "Price :"
    read price
  echo -n "Qty Available  : "
    read available 
  echo -n "Qty Sold : "
    read sold 


  echo $title:$author:$price:$available:$sold >> BookDB.txt
  echo $BookDB "New book title ' $title ' added successfully "
}
```

I want to display "THE BOOK ALREADY EXISTS" in case when a book named similarly from the file is entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function add_new_book
{
  echo "1) add_new_book"
  echo -n "Title :"
    read title
    grep -iqs "^$title:" BookDB.txt && echo "THE BOOK ALREADY EXISTS" && return

  echo -n "Author :"
    read author
  echo -n "Price :"
    read price
  echo -n "Qty Available  : "
    read available 
  echo -n "Qty Sold : "
    read sold 
  echo $title:$author:$price:$available:$sold >> BookDB.txt
  echo $BookDB "New book title ' $title ' added successfully "
}
```

Comment: Wooww , just awesome. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the book, check if it exists:

```
     grep "$title" BookDB.txt >/dev/null 2>&1
     rc=$?

     if [[ "$rc" != 0 ]]; then
        echo $title:$author:$price:$available:$sold >> BookDB.txt
        echo $BookDB "New book title ' $title ' added successfully "
     else
        echo "The book $title already exists."
     fi
```

Comment: your answer was soo helpful 
thank you 

but could you please explain alone !!!

 rc=$?

     if [[ "$rc" != 0 ]];